# Clickonce upgrade error transitioning dot net versions 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, clickonce

My team has encountered an issue during an upgrade of a Clickonce application from dot net 2.0 to dot net 4.0.

Furthermore, we are suspicious that this is an error in the Clickonce toolchain.

Core symptoms:

- Clickonce upgrades error, once, when upgrading between versions
- Using the same code I was able to publish non-error version locally, but the build server always produced error versions
- There are logged errors about verifying the manifest of specific files
- After the error, re-running the application upgrades correctly, using a different dialogue, without error.
- After installing 'windows management framework 4.0' my local machine now always appears to produce error versions

Here is the scenario we initially encountered:

Our large enterprise app has a thick client that is installed and distributed using the Microsoft Clickonce publishing platform.

We have a 3.8.90.24 version which is dot net 2.0.

Our next release is 3.8.100.19 (so far) which is dot net 4.0.

We have a deployment of the first version on the server. Note this particular scenario is hosted at a URL, but it also works using file path deployments.

We have an installed Clickonce client from the first version.

We deploy the upgraded version on the server, deleting the previous version entirely, and replacing the files.

When the Clickonce client is next run, we are prompted to upgrade (as is usual and expected), then click 'ok'.

At this point an error dialogue is displayed:

```
An error occured while trying to check for updates to the application.
Do you want to attempt to reinstall from the original installation location?
[ Yes ] [ No ]
```

Choosing Yes reinstalls, which works correctly (as does a manual un/re install)

Choosing No launches the old client. If you then close the client, and open the application again, it upgrades correctly.

This was a confusing set of symptoms.

I set up logging and found the following:

- The published files from the build server, in the drop folder or later laid down by our installer always errored.
- A local Clickonce published from the same code in the IDE did not error, from a URL or a local Directory.
- Building from the command line, also did not error, e.g.:

  ```
  msbuild /target:publish /p:PublishUrl=http://[FooApplication]/Clickonce/ /p:PublishDir=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ClickOnce\
  ```
- Then, because I wanted to check file hashes, I installed the "windows management framework 4.0" to get powershell 4.0 with the Get-FileHash command, and rebooted.
- After the reboot, I discovered that now previously working publishes, and all new local publishes exhibited the error.

I followed these guides and turned on verbose logging.

- Troubleshooting ClickOnce Deployments
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb94w1t5.aspx
- How to log clickonce deployment errors:
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404265.aspx
- How to specify verbose log files for clickonce deployments
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996997.aspx

Here I found some variations on the errors.

Below are key excerpts from the logs (and I'm happy to provide more if desired):

The 'prep' install, and the upgrades from that version start with this platform info:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 2.0.50727.5485
System.Deployment.dll       : 2.0.50727.5488 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
mscorwks.dll            : 2.0.50727.5485 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)
```

Fresh installs of the new version, or the SECOND run of the installers after upgrade attempts have this info:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18444
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34244 built by: FX452RTMGDR
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34244 built by: FX452RTMGDR
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)
```

Interesting that not only the version information changed, but also the structure of the platform.

An interesting sequence of event occurs in the original error log I captured before the install / reboot:

- The original application installs with the first platform info
- The upgrade is attempted, with the first platform info
- The upgrade fails with an error, and the application is closed.
- The application is restarted, and upgrades correctly with a different dialogue, with the SECOND platform info

Here are two of the errors from different scenarios:

Doing the upgrade from the 'Live Install' files:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 2.0.50727.5485
System.Deployment.dll       : 2.0.50727.5488 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
mscorwks.dll            : 2.0.50727.5485 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

[-SNIP-]

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [1/12/2015 2:38:45 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
    - Exception occurred loading manifest from file [my.app.namespace].Shared.XmlSerializers.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. 
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeCore(Boolean blocking)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
    - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    - Source: 
    - Stack trace:

[-SNIP-]
(There is nothing listed under the final 'stack trace' line)
```

Doing the upgrade from a local IDE publish:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 2.0.50727.5485
System.Deployment.dll       : 2.0.50727.5488 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
mscorwks.dll            : 2.0.50727.5485 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

[-SNIP-]

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [1/12/2015 3:01:28 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestLoad)
    - Exception occurred loading manifest from file [my.app.namespace.client].Shared.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. 
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ManifestLoadExceptionHelper(Exception exception, String filePath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeCore(Boolean blocking)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (InvalidManifest)
    - Cannot load internal manifest from component file.
    - Source: 
    - Stack trace:

[-SNIP-]
```

Note that these are DIFFERENT DLL FILES! (These are consistent for each individual publish, the difference is between the version from the full build process vs a local IDE publish)

At this point, as far as I can tell, when transitioning between dot net 2.0 and 4.0, the Clickonce deployment is having problems verifying manifest files. Once it swaps over to using the dot net 4.0 toolkit, everything is fine again.

This will be confusing to our users, 'no' means they are running an outdated client temporarily, and 'yes' means they lose some local settings.

I have wild speculation that the hashing algorithm or other machinery in the verification process changed, and the upgrade attempts to use the 2.0 version, which is not 100% compatible.

Any my actual questions:

- Has anyone encountered this before? It has resisted googling so far, although some similar signing problems show up from time to time, this specific upgrade scenario has eluded me.
- What further information could I gather that may be helpful?
- How can I solve or work around this issue, considering we have the previous version in the field at multiple locations, and the new version has not yet been released?